# Nework connection to Azure VM is slow

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, azure-vm

I have a Azure VM and Im experiencing a slow connection to VM via SSH.
I can connect using ssh or putty, but after some time VM drop the connection. Sometimes I get a connection timeout when I'm trying to connect to VM.

To try to identify the problem I created a new VM and tried to connect through the private interface, but I'm still having the same problem.

To illustrate the problema see the scp command:

```
escola@othervm:~$ scp  escola@10.0.0.4:backup/backup.dmp.gz .

backup.dmp.gz                        1% 1520KB 144.7KB/s   12:45 ETA
```

the command is executed and after a while download stops.
Any Help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience, you may increase the VM size to provide more memory for your VM. If it does not make sense. You could try the following solutions and refer to [this](https://bobcares.com/blog/ssh-connection-keeps-dropping/).

- Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to set the a large value of `ClientAliveCountMax`. The value is per minute. Then restart ssh service with `service sshd reload`.
- On the user `.ssh` directory, add `ServerAliveInterval 60` in the config file in `/user/.ssh/config`

For more information, you could read [detailed SSH troubleshooting steps for issues connecting to a Linux VM in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/detailed-troubleshoot-ssh-connection).

Comment: Thanks Nancy. I moved my VMs to digital ocean.